# asp.net 5.0.3 identity Authorization not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

i build a website with asp.net mvc 5 i use identity 3 and use authorize attribute for controlers
But even though I'm logged in, it still takes me to the login page

startup.cs :

```
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

controller:

```
 [Authorize]
        public async  Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
}
```

sign in action :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            model.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            ViewData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                    model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
                }

                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "اکانت شما به دلیل پنج بار ورود ناموفق به مدت پنج دقیقه قفل شده است";
                    return View(model);
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "رمزعبور یا نام کاربری اشتباه است");
            }
            return View(model);

        }
```

Comment: "even though I'm logged in". How do WE know you are logged in? Please post to the code for the action that logs the user in.

Comment: @JuanR I updated my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to register authentication before authorization:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

1. cAsE sEnSiTiViTy:

Lower case here:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="admin")]
```

Upper case here:

```
if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
```

2. Have you actually added the user in question to the role? Please post that code so we can see what you are doing (particularly the casing).
3. Server time zone. Make sure you consider server vs. client zones. I don't know if this is a problem with Identity but it has bitten me in the past.

Comment: no I test [Authorize] only and problem not fixed